# i would like to save my picture done with python's turtle, and then do an other picture

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

i have a simple turtle programm that draws something
after i have written this (i dont like eps but did not find how to change the picture format, anyway that's not my main question)

```
ts = getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="duck68.eps")
```

it works fine
then i add :

```
done()
mainloop()
[instructions for drawing]
ts = getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="duck69.eps")
```

and i draw something else : but on the second image created it seems that the first one has not been cleared before

(my idea after is to programm 100 pictures depending on a variable that moves say from 1 to 100 and that python to save them automatically one by one, even if it takes one hour to perform)

so my question is : after the `ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="duck68.eps")` instruction, what should i write so that the programm cancels the screen and just go on to create a second image

i precize that for this process i dont realy need the picture to be displayed on the screen while the program works : i need only that the picture be recorder

i was expecting to get the second image starting on a blank screen, however the first picture seems not to have been canceled

Comment: sorry it's done, that was just clear()